# Pytransitions queued hierarchical machine ends always in init state

Tags: python, pytransitions

I'm using the pytransitions with HierarchicalMachine class to be able to create small nested machines to complete subtasks inside a bigger state machine. I'm using the queued transitions to be able to invoke a trigger from inside of the state callback.

I would expect the following code ends in prepare_waiting state, but it actually goes back to prepare_init state.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

**Code:**

```
from transitions.extensions.factory import HierarchicalMachine
import logging as log

QUEUED = True

class PrepareMachine(HierarchicalMachine):
    def __init__(self):

        states = [
            {"name": "init", "on_enter": self.entry_init},
            {"name": "connecting", "on_enter": self.entry_connecting},
            {"name": "waiting", "on_enter": self.entry_waiting},
        ]

        super().__init__(states=states, initial="init", queued=QUEUED)

    def entry_init(self):
        print("common entry point ...")
        self.to_connecting()

    def entry_connecting(self):
        print("connecting multiple indtruments ...")
        self.to_waiting()

    def entry_waiting(self):
        print("wait for response ...")

class ProductionMachine(HierarchicalMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        prepare = PrepareMachine()
        states = ["init", {"name": "prepare", "children": prepare}]
        super().__init__(states=states, initial="init", queued=QUEUED)
        self.add_transition("start_testing", "init", "prepare")

log.basicConfig(level=log.INFO)
machine = ProductionMachine()
machine.start_testing()
print(machine.state)
```

**Output:**

```
INFO:transitions.core:Finished processing state init exit callbacks.
INFO:transitions.core:Finished processing state prepare enter callbacks.
common entry point ...
INFO:transitions.core:Finished processing state init exit callbacks.
connecting multiple indtruments ...
INFO:transitions.core:Executed callback '<bound method PrepareMachine.entry_connecting of <__main__.PrepareMachine object at 0xb6588bd0>>'
INFO:transitions.core:Finished processing state connecting enter callbacks.
INFO:transitions.core:Finished processing state connecting exit callbacks.
wait for response ...
INFO:transitions.core:Executed callback '<bound method PrepareMachine.entry_waiting of <__main__.PrepareMachine object at 0xb6588bd0>>'
INFO:transitions.core:Finished processing state waiting enter callbacks.
INFO:transitions.core:Executed callback '<bound method PrepareMachine.entry_init of <__main__.PrepareMachine object at 0xb6588bd0>>'
INFO:transitions.core:Finished processing state init enter callbacks.
prepare_init
```

Comment: So after some debugging, I found out that entry_init doesn't work in queued fashion and is kept on the call stack until the end. Therefore the prepare_init state at the end. The entry_connecting works as expected. But no solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short: `self` in callbacks of `PrepareMachine` does not refer to the right model.

Long:

#### What is happening and why?

To understand why this is happening one has to consider the concept of `pytransitions` that splits a state machine into a 'rule book' (e.g. `Machine`) containing all state, event and transition definition and the stateful object which is usually referred to as the model. All convenience functions such as trigger functions (methods named after transition names) or auto transitions (such as `to_<state>`) are attached to the model.

```py
machine = Machine(model=model, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="initial")
assert model.is_initial()  # 
model.to_work()  # auto transition
assert model.is_work()
machine.to_initial() <-- will raise an exception
```

When you do not pass a model parameter to a `Machine`, the machine itself will act as a model and thus get all the convenience and trigger functions attached to it.

```py
machine = Machine(states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="A")
assert machine.is_A()
machine.to_B()
assert machine.is_B()
```

So, in your example, `prepare = PrepareMachine()` makes `prepare` act as its own model and `machine = ProductionMachine()` makes `machine` the model of `ProductionMachine`. This is why you can call for instance `prepare.to_connecting()` because `prepapre` acts a model, too. However, not the model you want that is `machine`. So if we change your example slightly things might get a bit clearer:

```py
class ProductionMachine(HierarchicalMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prepare = PrepareMachine()
        states = ["init", {"name": "prepare", "children": self.prepare}]
# [...]
machine = ProductionMachine()
machine.start_testing()
print(machine.state)  #  >>> prepare_init
print(machine.prepare.state)  # >>> waiting
```

With `machine.start_testing()` you let `machine` enter `prepare_init` and consequently call `PrepareMachine.entry_init`. In this method you call `self.to_connecting()` which triggers a transition of `prepare` to `connecting` and *NOT* `machine`. When `prepare` enters `connecting`, `PrepareMachine.entry_connecting` will be called and `self` (aka `prepare`) will transition once again with `to_waiting`. As both, `PrepareMachine` and `ProductionMachine`, process events queued, `prepare` will finish `to_connecting` and instantly process `to_waiting`. At this point `machine` is still processing `entry_init` since self.to_connection (aka `prepare.to_connecting`) has not returned yet. So when `prepare` finally reaching the `waiting` state, `machine` will return and log that it is now done with processing transitions callbacks for `start_testing`. The model `machine` did not revert to `prepare_init` but all the processing of `prepare` happens *WHILE* `start_testing` is processed and this causes the log messages of `start_testing` wrapping all the other messages.

#### How to achieve what you want?

We want to trigger the events (to_connecting/waiting) on the correct model (`machine`). There are multiple approaches to this. First, I would recommend to define 'proper' transitions instead of relying on auto transitions. Auto transitions are passed to `machine` as well (so `machine.to_connecting` will work), things could get messy when you have multiple substates with the same name.

##### Option A: Get the correct model from event_data.

When you pass `send_event=True` to `Machine` constructors, every callback can (and must) accept an `EventData` object that contains all information about the currently processed transition. This includes the model.

```py
        transitions = [
            ["connect", "init", "connecting"],
            ["connected", "connecting", "waiting"]
        ]

        states = [
            {"name": "init", "on_enter": self.entry_init},
            {"name": "connecting", "on_enter": self.entry_connecting},
            {"name": "waiting", "on_enter": self.entry_waiting},
        ]
# ...

    def entry_init(self, event_data):
        print("common entry point ...")
        event_data.model.connect()
        # we could use event_data.model.to_connecting() as well
        # but I'd recommend defining transitions with 'proper' names
        # focused on events

    def entry_connecting(self, event_data):
        print("connecting multiple instruments ...")
        event_data.model.connected()

    def entry_waiting(self, event_data):
        print("wait for response ...")
# ...

        super().__init__(states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="init", queued=QUEUED, send_event=True)
```

##### Option B: Use callback names instead of references and pass them directly to `on_enter`.

When callback parameters are names, `transitions` will resolve callbacks on the currently processed model. The parameter `on_enter` allows to pass multiple callbacks and also mix references and strings. So your code could look like this.

```py
from transitions.extensions.factory import HierarchicalMachine
import logging as log

QUEUED = False


class PrepareMachine(HierarchicalMachine):
    def __init__(self):
     
        transitions = [
            ["connect", "init", "connecting"],
            ["connected", "connecting", "waiting"]
        ]

        states = [
            {"name": "init", "on_enter": [self.entry_init, "connect"]},
            {"name": "connecting", "on_enter": [self.entry_connecting, "connected"]},
            {"name": "waiting", "on_enter": self.entry_waiting},
        ]
        super().__init__(states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="init", queued=QUEUED)

    def entry_init(self):
        print("common entry point ...")

    def entry_connecting(self):
        print("connecting multiple indtruments ...")

    def entry_waiting(self):
        print("wait for response ...")


class ProductionMachine(HierarchicalMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        self.prepare = PrepareMachine()
        states = ["init", {"name": "prepare", "children": self.prepare}]
        super().__init__(states=states, initial="init", queued=QUEUED)
        self.add_transition("start_testing", "init", "prepare")

log.basicConfig(level=log.INFO)
machine = ProductionMachine()
machine.start_testing()
assert machine.is_prepare_waiting()
```

Note that I had to switch `QUEUED=False` since in `transitions` 0.8.8 and earlier, there is a [bug](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/issues/544) related to queued processing of nested transitions. **UPDATE:** This bug has been fixed in `transitions` 0.8.9 which was released just now. `QUEUED=True` should now work as well.

Comment: Many thanks for the deep explanation. I'm already using events and "proper transitions", I just wanted to make the example as short and simple as possible. Both solutions work for me, I like solution A more as the event is triggered directly inside the callback function. If you are in Prague, the beer is on me :)

Comment: @HonzaKrejci: Best offer. There are hardly any better combinations than (czech) beer and Prague (in my world at least) :). Your example was well-written and helped me track a bug. FYI: 0.8.9 was just released. `QUEUED=True` should now work as well.

Comment: Thanks again, It's outstanding support. I have corrected my code and updated to 0.8.9. QUEUED=True works for my example and also for the real-life code as expected.